# autocomplete="on" does not insert value into value="my value"

Tags: html, css, forms, validation, input

I have a input field with the labels: `autocomplete="on"` and `value=""`. When I Go back and come again on the site the values are in the field but not in the **value tag**.

My HTML Code:

```
<div class="inputBox">
    <input type="email" name="email" autocomplete="on" onkeyup="this.setAttribute('value', this.value);" required value="">
    <label>E-Mail</label>
</div><br>
```

My CSS(I'm not sure if you need it):

```
.inputBox input:focus ~ label,
.inputBox input:valid ~ label,
.inputBox input:not([value=""]) ~ label {
 /*My Style*/
}
```

[Example Image (Right of the  `required` is  `value`)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7lqZ9.png)

Feel free to ask me for more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to save the value of the email field as soon as it is entered or when the window is navigated away.

The values can be stored either in [Session Storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) (lost when the current tab is closed) or in [Local Storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) (will persist even if the tab or browser is closed).

Once we have saved our values, we can use the saved values to pre-fill our input fields once the user is back on the page.

This can be achieved by the below code

```
// save the field to local or session storage before navigating to other page
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', (event) => {
  localStorage["email"] = document.querySelector("input[type='email']").value;
  console.log("Value saved");
});

// apply values from the local or session storage on document load
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", (event) => {
  document.querySelector("input[type='email']").value = localStorage["email"];
  console.log("Value applied from storage");
});
```

[Here's a working sample fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kmarb23o/6/) based on your code. Try inputting an email and then refreshing the page.